# Create a "Scrollable Table" in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I want to create a table like the one attached where people can enter data on the white fields like normal, but when they press the arrows on the week to change what week they are viewing it changes the value of the cells without formula inside them. If they go to a new week it would be blank, if they go to an old week it shows previous data entered.

This image shows the table (Wingdings icons have been used to now show names or data):
[image: screenshot]

Comment: It's possible to make a scrollable table (dashboard) based on a sheet, but it won't be updatable. Does that interest you?

Answer (score 0):

In **Excel** something like this would be done by having separate sheets per week, and switching between them by going to the correct sheet.

What you really seem to want is not a spreadsheet type of functionally, but rather a program like **Access** will let you create something like that (but *Access* is obviously not as simple to use as *Excel*.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, that is our current system but people keep creating new tabs by copying the wrong stuff, hence why i wanted to make a single tab system. Is there any way to make it then so that when a new tab is created it is already filled with a draft, though i am willing to learn access, how easy would this be to do in access?

Comment: That's the bread and butter of Access... So it's not a very complicated thing to do (But that's in Access's terms of complexity... which is quite a stretch from Excel's...) In Access you create a "Form" and fill it with the field and data you want, and that form can show based on selection/slider.

Comment: awesome, thank you very much i will have to give it a go

Comment: Great, you can come back and let us know... As for doing "something" in Excel, you might get away with creating a Button which executes a macro to do the "copy" correctly (I can't tell you exact directions since it's I don't understand so well your data scenario and also since we're not a code writing site... but the keywords to search would be something like ***excel button to create new sheet from template*** or something similar.)